# In NodeJS, how do I specify one ca certificate for client certificate checking, and another for showing the certificate chain to the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, certificate, client-certificates

I'm trying to write a program that uses client certificate authentication as my primary authentication method.  I have a certificate signed for my website that I want to have this application use.  I read http://blog.nategood.com/nodejs-ssl-client-cert-auth-api-rest and was going to implement my server as described by this person's article, but I would like to present my signed certificate to browsers, and then sign certificates they generate with the keygen attribute with my own certificate authority.

example code:

```
var https = require("https");
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

var options = {
    key:fs.readFileSync("./myserver.key"),
    cert:fs.readFileSync("./server.crt"),
    ca:fs.readFileSync("server.ca_bundle"),
    //I want to have a separate certificate for checking client certificates here, but I would be ok with any solution to the problem.
    requestCert:true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false   
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, "Content-type: text/plain");
    res.write("Authorized: "+JSON.stringify(req.client.authorized))
}).listen(443);
```

Comment: If you want your own CA as the only authority for authorising connections, shouldn't you simply be passing your own CA certificate as the `ca` parameter?

Comment: I want one certificate (that is signed by a CA, but is not a CA) to be presented with the full certificate chain from the signer, and a different one for client certificate verification.

Comment: Yes, the cert to be presented should be in `key`/`cert`, your own CA for verification should be in `ca`.